# Wifi and wifi hotspot at once

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, wifi-hotspot, access-point

I have wifi adapter TP-Link **TL-WN722N**
I want to use it to access internet and to share wifi access point at once.

I did it on windows 8:

```
netsh
wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid="APname" key="mykey" keyUsage=persistent 
wlan start hostednetwork
```

How can i do this from ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: is there any news about it?

Answer (score 0):

It has been explained nicely [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84440/hotspot-and-internet-access-together-why-not). You need an app called [`create_ap`](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap).

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! If an answer works for two different questions, then it is very likely that the questions are duplicates.  In these cases, the best course of action is to flag the post as a duplicate.  Right under the post is a flag button.  Thanks.